# Running test suite setup once in every node of Selenium Grid

Tags: c#, appium, nunit, grid

I am testing an application which would require to configure it into dev mode before test execution. (set the application to point into dev backend instead of live) The configuration itself is happening on the application UI.
I am using NUnit as a test runner for the framework, with Appium and Selenium Grid.

What I tried was to create a `OneTimeSetup` for the dev configuration, but I noticed that it is being executed only before the first testcase on the first node.

What I would really need is to execute this UI configuration at every Appium node once, but I am out of ideas. Anyone encountered this, or have some tips how to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SetUp] attribute for your UI configuration method. This will ensure that the UI configuration is executed for every test. Hope this helps